# dash: parse string into two variables

Tags: shell-script, dash

I have a dash script, and I need to parse `$1`, which is a string containing two parts separated by '`:`', such as `foo:123`. I would like to to save `foo` in $X and `123` in $Y.

I thought I could use `read`:

```
$ echo "foo:123" | tr ':' ' ' | read X Y
```

but that does not work (no error given)

```
$ echo $X
```

gives empty line as output.

Why does my `read` construct not work?
And how could I achieve my goal (any solution, does not have to use read)

Comment: Parameter expansion works:  `var="foo:123"; echo "${var#*:}"; echo "${var%:*}"`

Comment: `echo` doesn't survive the pipe. You can use Process Substitution to achieve what you want:  E.g `read -r X Y < <(echo "foo:123" | tr ':' ' '); echo "$X"`

Comment: @val0x00ff There's no process substitution in dash.

Comment: @val0x00ff - process substitution works in bash, but not in dash.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I didn't check that!  Now I learned something!  THanks

Comment: `dash` is a POSIX-compliant shell, so what you are looking for is a portable way. Parameter expansion in jasonwryan example is the best (fast, simple and portable).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [dash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash), each command in [*Pipelines*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02) [run in subshell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12) (`zsh` and AT&T `ksh`, [the rightmost command in pipelines doesn't](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html#l70)), so variables `X` and `Y` are no longer existed when your command done.

Simply, you can use [*Parameter Expansion*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), try:

```
$ set -- foo:123
$ X=${1%:*}
$ Y=${1#*:}
```

---

The example is used for interactive session.

Inside your script, you don't need `set -- foo:123`.

Comment: @uonglm - thankss, that works. Why do I need the `set --` ?

Comment: @MartinVegter: `set` used for set or unset shell options and positional parameters. In this example, `set -- foo:123` set `$1` to `foo:123`. `--` marked end of options, let you work with variables start with a dash `-`.

Comment: They don't have to run in subshells. All but one have to run in subshells. In AT&T ksh or zsh the rightmost one doesn't. In bash and dash they all run in subshells.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks, updated my answer. I can find the documentation for `zsh`, but `ksh` can't. Can you show me what part of `ksh` documentation mention this behaviour?

Comment: @cuonglm, for `ksh`, I don't think it's documented in the man page, but it's been the case since the 80s so it's fairly wide-spread knowledge. Note that only applies to the AT&T (original) and zsh implementations of `ksh`, not the `pdksh`/`mksh`... one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I wasn't even born at that time :) Thanks again for your information. And another question, what do you mean `zsh implementations of ksh`?

Comment: `zsh` can be considered as another implementation of `ksh` since it has a `ksh` emulation mode (for instance when called as `ksh`). With that, it has more in common with ksh93 than say  pdksh. There's no _standard_ that covers `ksh`. So if pdksh is considered a ksh, why not zsh in ksh emulation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Ah, it makes sense. I'm often familiar with phase `zsh in ksh emulation`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the *split+glob* operator (leave a variable unquoted) (and which you used for no apparent reason in your question):

```
IFS=:     # configure the split part to use : as the delimiter
set -f    # disable the glob part
set -- $1 # $1 is split on : and parts are stored in $1, $2...
X=$1 Y=$2
```

You can also do:

```
printf '%s\n' "$1" | {
  IFS=: read -r X Y
  printf '%s\n' "$X"
}
```

In `dash` like `bash` (but contrary to AT&T `ksh` or `zsh`), all parts of a pipeline run in subshells (they need to run in different processes anyway since they run concurrently). Above, we need the part that uses that `$X` to be in that subshell that reads the output of `printf` and *sets* `$X`.

Note that those two solutions behave differently if `$1` contains a newline character or more than one `:` character.